# Prove that after a certain positive number all numbers can be represented as a positive linear combination of two coprime numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

My attempt: I have an idea about frobenius numbers but I didn't want to use the result.So i started with the basics: let two numbers be a, b such that gcd(a,b)=1.

Now $a>=1$and $ab>=b$.since $b.a+a.0=ab$so from here I can get an intuition that numbers after$ ab$can be written as a linear combination.

Now I try to prove that $ab+k=ax+by$where $x, y, k$are all positive numbers. Now we note one idea that gcd(a,b)=1 and so $au+bv=1 $(by bezouts identity) . And so $k=am+bn$
Where m and n can be positive or negative. Now suppose m is negative and n is positive. Then $ab+k=a(b+m)+bn$if the coefficient of a is still negative then we can have $a(b+m+yb)+b(n-ya)$.we chose $b+m+yb<b.y<-\frac{m}{b}$.now $-ya>\frac{ma}{b}$. And $n-ya>\frac{k}{b}$which is positive.

$1)$if there are flaws in my answer can someone find it out and also how do I do the same proof using Euclids division algorithm

$2)$can someone drop some hints about how do I do it for n numbers

Edit1:suppose there are $n$ Coprime numbers. $a_q,a_2,a_3,..a_n$.Now I do the same thing $a_1(a_2+..a_n)>=a_1$ and similarly $a_1(a_2+..a_n)+a_2.0+a_3.0+..a_n.0=a_1(a_2+..a_n)$ .

So I try to prove that a number greater than this will be represented. They are coprime so their Gcd is 1 .hence $a_1.x_1+a_2.x_2+..a_n.x_n =1$.$a_1.y_1+..a_n.y_n=k$.(k has the same definition as above.)

Now,  consider the worst case that$ y_2,..y_n$ are negative  . By similar arguments in case (1) i show that the coefficients are all positives.

Comment: Take a look at [Chicken_McNugget_Theorem](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Chicken_McNugget_Theorem)

Comment: @Demonix_Hermit Could you please go through my way of proof and point out whether there is mistake or not..

Comment: I believe that English is not your first language, which makes it tough to write a coherent proof. But much of your "proof" consists of sentence fragments ("Where m and n can be negative") rather than sentences, and such things are neither right nor wrong --- they're meaningless. Can you perhaps rewrite carefully? One possibility is a two-column proof, where you write statements, and for each statement, a reason. Example:

S1: $\gcd(a, b)= 1$; R1: Given.

S2: There are integers $u,v$ with $au + bv = 1$; R2: Bezout's identity. 

S3:  ...; R3